# Node Js passing parameters to an "off the shelf" callback

Tags: node.js

I have a library that makes a web request and passes the results to a callback like the sample below:

```
someReadyWebSearchThirdPartyLibrary.getSearch(parameters, error, callback);
```

Then the callback is something like:

```
var callback = function (data) {
    console.log(data);
};
```

Is there a way I can pass more arguments to the callback from the caller given this is an off the shelf ready library?

Answer (score 1):

just define your "first" callback inline, there you can pass more parameters:

```
someReadyWebSearchThirdPartyLibrary.getSearch(parameters, error, function(data) {
  callback(data, otherVar1, otherVar2);
});
```

Then your callback could look something like this:

```
var callback = function (data, otherVar1, otherVar2) {
    console.log(data);
    console.log(otherVar1);
    console.log(otherVar2);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Without editing the code of the library that calls the callback, you can't change what is passed to that specific callback.  But, there are multiple options where you can get access to other variables:

**Inline callback accessing variables in scope**

you can use scope and an inline definition to make other variables available (via scoping) to the callback.

```
let someVar1 = "foo";
let someVar2 = 4;

someReadyWebSearchThirdPartyLibrary.getSearch(parameters, error, function(data) {
   // can access data, someVar1 and someVar2 here as they are all in scope
   console.log(someVar1);
});
```

---

**Use `.bind()` to add arguments to the callback**

You could also use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) to create a new function that adds parameters.

```
function callback(someVar1, someVar2, data) {
    console.log(someVar1);
}

someReadyWebSearchThirdPartyLibrary.getSearch(parameters, error, callback.bind(null, "foo", 4));
```

`.bind()` creates a new function that adds additional arguments before calling the actual `callback()` function.

---

**Make your own stub function**

Or, make your own stub function that calls your callback (essentially what the `.bind()` option was doing for you):

```
function mycallback(someVar1, someVar2, data) {
    console.log(someVar1);
}

someReadyWebSearchThirdPartyLibrary.getSearch(parameters, error, function(data) {
   mycallback("foo", 4, data);
});
```

Comment: Thank you for the great answer pal ! I wonder, could you maybe have a look at this one as well : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57972076/nodejs-recursive-service-call-with-callback-function

Comment: @CapBaracudas - if this answered your question then please click the check mark to the left of the answer to indicate that to the community and that will also earn you some reputation points here on stack overflow for following the proper procedure.

Answer (score 0):

I assume your callback arguments are variable and that the function is defined in an isolated manner (where it can't access scope beyond itself, and that you don't want to mutate the callback function's underlying data.  It also assumes that Data is an object (You should perform some validation on this though). Therefore you could do something like the following:

```
someReadyWebSearchThirdPartyLibrary.getSearch(parameters, error, function(data) { 
  data.newArgument = 'lorem';
  callback(data); 
});
```

This way you can add any arbitrary arguments onto the data object passed.